# PT100 calibration

Tags: resistance, temperature

If I take (say) a class B PT100 sensor with a stated absolute accuracy of +/- 0.3 deg and calibrate it with a freezing/boiling chemical at (say) 50 deg will that make it inherently more accurate when I do a temperature correction anywhere in the range based on that reading? If the known temperature is accurate to (say) 0.001 deg?

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159172/2451

Comment: Do you want accuracy to milli Kelvin or just stability?  (Besides the triple point of water, won't there be local pressure corrections to your liquid bath at the milli-K level?)  If the temperature range is near room temp, then maybe a thermistor (R ~10k ohm) would be better?  higher dV/dT.    (I don't know about long term drift.)

Comment: Repeatability is not a problem - but we need absolute temperature

Comment: Absolute temperature to milli-K near room temp?  Can you talk about the application?  I just can't imagine what needs that level of accuracy

Comment: I can't really comment on the device, but in one mode of use it could act as a thermometer with sub milliKelvin resolution. In another mode, it can measure distances down to 50nm. There is a trade-off between modes. If we know one, we can measure the other.

Comment: Interferomemter, Fabry-Perot cavity?  Sub mill-K resolution is not uncommon.  (The dV/dT of a thermistor is ~ 50-100mV/K)  But who needs that kind of accuracy?.. For any kind of extended object I would guess that most of the time it has (at least) a milli-K gradient across it.  (Oh you should include my name if you want me to know you responded... otherwise I might not check back.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold The problem is absolute accuracy and also stability over time. Not sure a thermistor is good enough

Comment: Please do not move this to chat - this is my last comment. I have determined how I can calibrate the PT100 in absolute terms to better than a mK at zero cost using a feature the instrument I am developing. I would really like to explain, but I expect my company will probably want to patent it. Thanks to all who have contributed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm hardly an expert in PTDs, but I have a good deal of experience in building data acquisition/telemetry/control systems. If you're looking for *resolution* of .001 C, a PTD will work fine - so long as the entire system is physically stable.

This http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer is a good place to start.

The problem with getting .001 *accuracy* is not so much the sensor as all the rest of the system. For instance, where the platinum transitions to copper for the output leads, you get thermocouple effects. If you use a current source to excite the PTD and read voltage as the output, the temperature gradient between the sensor and the measurement device will alter the resistance of the copper wires and introduce temperature errors, so if you move the sensor you get changing temperatures over the leads, and changing output voltages. This may or may not be a problem depending on things like wire size and length. Thermocouple effects are microvolt level, but (for instance) for a PT100 at 0 C excited by 10 mA, a .001 degree change gives 3.9 microvolts.

For less than $100, you're in for a tussle.

Comment: 10mA will cause huge self-heating errors- we use 10uA into a 1000 ohm RTD in one special application. The instrumentation design is non-trivial to get down to uK.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I thought the 10 mA was to show, "the best" dV/dT, for the pt100.  (I've mostly put 10k RTDs in 5V bridges.. I don't worry much about self heating, as long as it's small and constant.)

Comment: Yeah. I intentionally used an unrealistically high excitation current to show that, even with such a high current thermocouple effects can be a problem. And at 100 uA, the effects are, relatively, 100 times worse. Although 10 mA into 100 ohms will "only" give 10 mW, so it's not all THAT extreme. Good heatsinking covers a number of design flaws.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Agreed- it shows clearly that a DC design could have issues. Care also needs to be taken with the specs(manship) on RTDs- they often show the self-heating in air at 1m/s, oil or even flowing water.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, especially if the measurement is near the single-point calibration, but it may be difficult to quantify, also it would depend on how you did the correction (a simple zero shift or perhaps a weighted deviation from the nominal curve, or something else).

It's non-trivial (to say the least) to make a real single-point temperature calibration to anything like that accuracy.

Comment: The bad news is that I need it ideally to be accurate to sub-milliKelvin resolution. Which is not going to happen, but if I can reduce the error margin I might be able to fudge it some other way.

Comment: Stability and resolution sub-mK at 50C is certainly achievable. Accuracy..  less so.

Comment: I really need to find an expert who can give me some info on how to do this cheaply. There's no point in putting this in an instrument if it is more than the retail price of the instrument itself.

Comment: @DirkBruere, what's the budget? A thermistor in a bridge with an instrument amp is not that much.

Comment: Budget is ideally <$100

Comment: Do what cheaply? Design cost or parts cost? Absolute accuracy or stability? The former is a metrology/experimentalist problem (triple point apparatus, controlling impurities to lots of nines, controlling self-heating and leadwire losses), the latter is electronics (instrumentation) design.

Comment: @DirkBruere, Re: "find an expert", You think Spehro is not an expert?  I find that insulting.

Comment: Why? Does Spehro spend all his time working on precision temperature measurement at the microKelvin level? Am I expected to know if he does?